# Reduction map from the generic to the special fibre

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, schemes

I have a few basic questions about Liu's [1, Section 10.1.3] description of the reduction map from the closed points of the generic fibre of a proper scheme over a complete DVR to its special fibre.  Here's (my slight paraphrasing of) the section that's bothering me:

> Let $R$ be a complete DVR and let $S = \operatorname{Spec}R$.  Let $s \in S$ be the closed point.  Let $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow S$ be a proper scheme over $S$ with generic fibre $X$ and special fibre $\mathcal{X}_s$.  For any closed point $x \in X$, the Zariski closure $\overline{\{x\}}$ is an irreducible finite scheme over $S$ and is therefore a local scheme with closed point $\overline{\{x\}} \cap \mathcal{X}_s$.

One then defines the reduction map $r\colon X^0 \rightarrow \mathcal{X}_s$, where $X^0$ is the set of closed points of $X$, by $r(x) = \overline{\{x\}} \cap \mathcal{X}_s$.  Here are my questions:

1. What is the point of considering the Zariski closure of a closed point?  By definition $x$ is closed precisely when $\{x\} = \overline{\{x\}}$, so this part of the definition seems redundant.  Am I missing something obvious?
2. More importantly, I don't understand how to interpret the intersection $\overline{\{x\}} \cap \mathcal{X}_s$ since the two sets in question don't share a common "parent" space.  What is the space in which the intersection is taking place?

Thanks in advance.

[1] Liu, Q., *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Oxford Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 6. Oxford University Press, 2002

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The point $x$ is closed as a subset of the generic fiber $X$, but not as a subspace of the big scheme  $\mathcal{X}$ over $S$ ; so it makes sense to take the closure of $x$ in the big scheme  $\mathcal{X}$.
2. Then you can take the intersection of this closure with the special fibre $\mathcal X_s$ : this intersection takes place in the big scheme $\mathcal{X}$, which is your "parent" scheme.

Maybe the source of the confusion is the simultaneous use of $X$ and $\mathcal{X}$ , which are typographically not sufficiently distinguishable?

Comment: The typography is definitely not the problem. I think the problem is that I'm having trouble seeing how to consider $X$ and $\mathcal{X}_s$ as being "in" $\mathcal{X}$.  They are both $\mathcal{X}$-schemes having been formed by fibre products, so should the expression $\overline{\{x\}} \cap \mathcal{X}_s$ be interpreted as $\pi_X(\overline{\{x\}}) \cap \pi_{\mathcal{X}_s}(\mathcal{X}_s)$ where $\pi_X\colon X \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ and $\pi_{\mathcal{X}_s}\colon \mathcal{X}_s \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ are the canonical projections?

Comment: Call $f:\mathcal X \to S$ your morphism of schemes.Then topologically $X$ is just the inverse image $X=f^{-1}(\eta )$ of the generic  point $\eta$ of $S$ and $\mathcal X_s=f^{-1}(s)$ the inverse image of the closed point $s$ of $S$. So $\mathcal X$ is just the disjoint union of its open subset $X$ and of its closed subset $\mathcal X_s$.  This business of fibre products (=base change) is useful for giving a scheme structure to fibres of morphisms but obscures a little the fact that you just deal with inverse images.

Comment: Excellent, your comment clears it up.  Thanks!